# collect rows and columns based on id matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use python and the pandas library. I want to collect the rows and columns from a data-frame according to one criteria, collect only those ids with a pattern like 'BIKE-\d\d\d\d' from a specific column 'BikeID'. I tried several versions of the following:

d1 = pandas.dataframe

```
d2 = d1[d1["BikeID"] == re.compile(r' (BIKE-\d\d\d\d)')]
```

but I am getting an empty data-frame instead. It works when it is specific:

```
d2 = d1[d1["BikeID"] == 'BIKE-0001']
```

,but I want to match all ids that have BIKE in the front. I would appreciate if you could show me a way of doing this task.

Comment: Mh, your question is very hard to read :(, please check this page and format your question accordingly : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to achieve this with the regex pattern `'(^BIKE-[\d]{4})'` this will look for strings that start with BIKE- and then 4 digits:

```
In [167]:
s= pd.Series(['BIKE-0001', 'BIKE','BIKE-000','sdBIKE-0001'])
s

Out[167]:
0      BIKE-0001
1           BIKE
2       BIKE-000
3    sdBIKE-0001
dtype: object

In [168]:
s.str.extract(r'(^BIKE-[\d]{4})', expand=False)

Out[168]:
0    BIKE-0001
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: Please post raw data, code to create your df and the desired output by editing your question

Comment: Thank you for this answer. As I said, the following: d2 = d1[d1["BikeID"] == 'BIKE-0001'] will store in the d2 data frame the row and all columns for the product with BikeID = BIKE-0001. BikeID ranges from Bike-0001 to Bike-0400. I want to collect in a data rame (d2) the rows and all columns of all products that their BikeID starts with BIKE. Do I have to import something to use str?

Comment: In that case then the pattern `s.str.extract(r'(^BIKE)', expand=False)` should work

Comment: To clarify `d2 = d1[d1['BikeID'].str.contains(r'^BIKE')]` should filter the df

Comment: In your example the code works. When I am using your code (with my data frame) I am getting an error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'. I don't understand why. Also, why the following: d2 = d1[d1["BikeID"] == re.compile(r' (^BIKE)')] is returning an empty data frame (named d2)?

Comment: did you try my last suggestion: `d2 = d1[d1['BikeID'].str.contains(r'^BIKE')]`

Comment: Yes, I am getting an error: ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: You'll need to post raw data, code, your attempts and the errors into your question otherwise I cannot help you